# TCPDF interactive pdf

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

Trying to allow outputs in PDF format from a website. One of the PDF's is a document that I have to build using data from a database, and just fill in a template. I'm using TCPDF to create the PDF files from the website.

Rather than having to construct the whole form in HTML and fill that in and convert it to PDF, I was wondering if I could have a pdf stored on the web hosting with the empty fields as interactive form fields, and fill it using TCPDF and the data from the database? Or if not, is there another way of doing this? Or is it just going to be simpler to build the form as an empty HTML shell and fill it in using database data before parsing to pdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot fill in a PDF form with TCPDF but you only can create one. You may use [FPDI](http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/) to import the PDF form ([without form fields!](http://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/after-importing-a-page-all-form-fields-are-gone/#question-206)) and write to the positions of the form fields manually. If you need to [fill in a PDF form with PHP](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-formfiller/details/) you may take a look at the [SetaPDF-FormFiller](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-formfiller/details/) component (not free!). It's that easy:

```
$document = SetaPDF_Core_Document::loadByFile('pdfForm.pdf');
$formFiller = new SetaPDF_FormFiller($document);
$fields = $formFiller->getFields();
$fields['name']->setValue('Your name');
$fields['age']->setValue('25');
$document->save()->finish();
```